# using ajenti like subdomain on web server

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain, config

I have a web server with nginx and I need to config ajenti to open like a subdomain, like this:

https://ajenti.mydomain.com/

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: could you solve this? I'm trying to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in your nginx-config?
It helped me ... Just look up nginx reverse proxy with ajenti. That might help too.

```
server {

        listen 443;

        ...

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        ...

}
```

Comment: Doing this results in a 403 auth error when I try to login.   When I connect directly over port 8000 the same credentials work.